# Jetpack Compose row: how to center one element and align the other to the end

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a row which contains two elements. I'd like the first element to be centered and the second one aligned to the end of the row. How can I do that?

[image: desired layout]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Composable
fun CenterAndEndAlignedRow() {
   Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = 
       Alignment.CenterEnd) {
         Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
         Text(text = "hey")
       }
       Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
         Text(text = "Okay")
      }
   }
}
```

The preview of the above method will be something like this:

[image: Preview]

Comment: it might overlap so I would recommend using a spacer to the left, and putting Row's horizontalArrangement to SpaceBetween

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution which will avoid overlaping elements

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    MaterialTheme() {
        Surface {
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
//                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.CropFree, contentDescription = "image")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(24.dp))
                Text(text = "Text")
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.CropFree, contentDescription = "image")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]